# How to iterate through a tree in spiral order?

Tags: data-structures

```
           1 
      2              3
  4       5        6       7
8  9   10   11   12 13   14  15
```

the output in spiral order should be 
1 3 2 4 5 6 7 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8

Comment: Esoteric application + no useful purpose == homework?

Comment: Why don't you make an attempt at your homework first, then ask us with some more educated questions

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried enumerating the levels all left-to-right (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you would iterate through the root node and the first level.

Can you write a function for that behavior, and call it recursively?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a variation of a breadth-first search. A breadth-first search uses a queue to get a list of the nodes at the next level down. A queue is a FIFO (first in first out). If you reverse the order at each level you'll get this effect so you need a LIFO (last in first out) instead, otherwise known as a stack.

Comment: A stack is not needed. A simple recursive walk will work, provided the nodes are called in the correct order.